# Rmarkdown does not reproduce bash code properly

Tags: r, bash, knitr, r-markdown, grass

I'm using Rmarkdown to show some bash code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "JPD"
date: "20 December 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r gp.setup, engine= 'bash', eval=FALSE}

##Change names to remove dots
g.rename raster=gp_ortho.1,gp_ortho_1,gp_ortho.2,gp_ortho_2,\
gp_ortho.3,gp_ortho_3

##Group bands together
i.group --verbose group=gp_combo input=gp_ortho_1@gp1,gp_ortho_2@gp1,\
gp_ortho_3@gp1
```
````

However, when knitted to html, the g.rename line(s) mostly disappear. For comparison, the i.group command beneath is displayed correctly:

[image: knitted]

What is it about the g.rename line of code that is doing this? Is it the `.`?

Answer (score 3):

`bash` treats dots/periods (`.`) as a command to execute what follows, so instead of printing the literal characters it's looking for files called `1`, `2`, and `3`.

I don't have GRASS set up to work without starting a session, but my guess is if you do it your script correctly interprets the `g.rename` command and looks for the raster files you specify.

I assume GRASS isn't set up in your Rmarkdown file so it's just printing the `g.rename...` characters then treating the `.` as a file to execute so isn't printing what follows. To get it to print correctly, use something other than `.` in your file names, set up your Rmarkdown session to understand `g.rename` as a command, or escape the characters with `\`:

````
```{r gp-setup, engine="bash", eval=FALSE}
# Change names to remove dots

g.rename raster=gp_ortho\.1,gp_ortho_1,gp_ortho\.2,gp_ortho_2, \
gp_ortho\.3,gp_ortho_3

## Group bands together
i.group --verbose group=gp_combo input=gp_ortho_1@gp1,gp_ortho_2@gp1, \
gp_ortho_3@gp1
```
````

Comment: `r.in.gdal` which precedes these commands natively names rasters with `.`s, hence me changing them. Annoyingly the escape slashes appear in the knitted document, but I guess that is the only work around. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JPD No problem, sorry it's not quite right. I can only suggesting trying to configure your knitr bash environment to be able to use GRASS commands. Or, if `r.in.gdal` produces actual files, use bash's native `mv`